# Python Pandas DataFrame Merge on Columns with Overwrite

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to merge two Pandas DataFrames, by matching on (and retaining) supplied columns, but overwriting all the rest?

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name", "Gender", "Age", "LastLogin", "LastPurchase"])
df1.loc[0] = ["Bob", "Male", "21", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-01"]
df1.loc[1] = ["Frank", "Male", "22", "2023-02-01", "2023-02-01"]
df1.loc[2] = ["Steve", "Male", "23", "2023-03-01", "2023-03-01"]
df1.loc[3] = ["John", "Male", "24", "2023-04-01", "2023-04-01"]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name", "Gender", "Age", "LastLogin", "LastPurchase"])
df2.loc[0] = ["Steve", "Male", "23", "2022-11-01", "2022-11-02"]
df2.loc[1] = ["Simon", "Male", "23", "2023-03-01", "2023-03-02"]
df2.loc[2] = ["Gary", "Male", "24", "2023-04-01", "2023-04-02"]
df2.loc[3] = ["Bob", "Male", "21", "2022-12-01", "2022-12-01"]

>>> df1
    Name Gender Age   LastLogin LastPurchase
0    Bob   Male  21  2023-01-01   2023-01-01
1  Frank   Male  22  2023-02-01   2023-02-01
2  Steve   Male  23  2023-03-01   2023-03-01
3   John   Male  24  2023-04-01   2023-04-01

>>> df2
    Name Gender Age   LastLogin LastPurchase
0  Steve   Male  23  2022-11-01   2022-11-02
1  Simon   Male  23  2023-03-01   2023-03-02
2   Gary   Male  24  2023-04-01   2023-04-02
3    Bob   Male  21  2022-12-01   2022-12-01
```

What I'd like is to end up with is `df1` updated with values from `df2`, if the `"Name"`, `"Gender"` and `"Age"` columns match. But without caring what the other columns are, so I'd end up with this:

```py
>>> df1
    Name Gender Age   LastLogin LastPurchase
0    Bob   Male  21  2022-12-01   2022-12-01 # Updated last two columns from df2
1  Frank   Male  22  2023-02-01   2023-02-01
2  Steve   Male  23  2022-11-01   2022-11-02 # Updated last two columns from df2
3   John   Male  24  2023-04-01   2023-04-01
```

I can do a merge like this:

```py
>>> df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=["Name", "Gender", "Age"], how='left')
```

But then I have to manually extract data from and drop the new columns created from the merge, using their names:

```py
>>> df3['LastLogin'] = df3['LastLogin_y'].fillna(df3['LastLogin_x'])
>>> df3['LastPurchase'] = df3['LastPurchase_y'].fillna(df3['LastPurchase_x'])
>>> df3.drop(['LastLogin_x', 'LastLogin_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> df3.drop(['LastPurchase_x', 'LastPurchase_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> 
>>> df3
    Name Gender Age   LastLogin LastPurchase
0    Bob   Male  21  2022-12-01   2022-12-01
1  Frank   Male  22  2023-02-01   2023-02-01
2  Steve   Male  23  2022-11-01   2022-11-02
3   John   Male  24  2023-04-01   2023-04-01
```

I'm trying to avoid this, as I need a generic way to update batches of data, and I don't know all their column names (just the ones I want to match on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the `_x`/`_y` columns by slicing only the the merging keys in `df1` for [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)/[`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with the original:

```
cols = ["Name", "Gender", "Age"]

df3 = df1[cols].merge(df2, how='left').fillna(df1)
```

A more convoluted approach using indexes:

```
df3 = (df2.set_index(cols)
          .combine_first(df1.set_index(cols))
          .reindex(df1[cols]).reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
    Name Gender Age   LastLogin LastPurchase
0    Bob   Male  21  2022-12-01   2022-12-01
1  Frank   Male  22  2023-02-01   2023-02-01
2  Steve   Male  23  2022-11-01   2022-11-02
3   John   Male  24  2023-04-01   2023-04-01
```

Comment: Thank you. The first approach is exactly what I'm after.